# Unable to connect docker's named volume database from sqlite3 using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sqlite, docker, docker-compose, node-sqlite3

We are running two container one is from Python flask and the other one is ExpressJS, we have created a docker volume manually `docker volume create --name localdb`, this volume runs fine with python app where I have created docker-compose and defined volume as external true.

We have inserted some data from Python and the records are exit, so we are trying to read the existing data from `lacaldb/reviews.db`

But it does not works for direct access via Docker run for ExpressJs App

Docker command:

```
docker container run -v localdb:/database --name dcserver --rm localserver:v1
```

Using `nodeJs v12` and `ExpressJs` with `SQlite3` for data storage, create Docker volume for Sqlite database, We have created the volume manually using docker command, and trying to access it via `docker run` command but getting an error.

Error:

```
[Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
Emitted 'error' event on Database instance at:
] {
  errno: 14,
  code: 'SQLITE_CANTOPEN'
}
```

Sample NodeJs Script:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
var db = new sqlite3.Database(process.env.LOCAL_DB_PATH)
console.log(process.env.LOCAL_DB_PATH)  // Prints "/localdb/reviews.db"

async function getReviews(){

             db.all(`SELECT * from REVIEWS`, [], function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.message)
                }
                console.log(res)
            }) 
}

export default getReviews
```

Inspected localdb volume:

```
$ docker volume inspect localdb

[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-04-03T17:01:29Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/localdb/_data",
        "Name": "localdb",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

docker-compose.yml         // here runs fine

```
version: "3.7"

services: 
    flask:
        build: ./flask
        container_name: flask
        restart: always
        environment: 
            - APP_NAME=myFlaskApp
        expose: 
            - 8080
        volumes: 
            - localdb:/database
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
volumes:
    localdb:
        external: true
```

Comment: You'll probably have a little more luck using a server-based database like PostgreSQL or MySQL; it will run in a separate container and you won't have to deal with the complexities of Docker filesystem sharing.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Due to system performance issues, we are using sqlite3, sqlite3 will not consume more CPU process right?

Comment: @DavidMaze, how better is `sequelize`

Comment: It might help you work in a dual-stack environment where you use SQLite for unit tests and a server-based relational database in Docker.  On its own it won't address the data storage problem, it's a question of what database you choose to put behind it.